# AWS api call with aws4fetch package in cloudflare workers?

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-js, cloudflare-workers

I'm not able to call AWS Api's using aws4fetch.

Could someone giveme an example on how to call S3 putobject using cloudflare workers ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The below code worked for me to upload a simple txt file from a cloudflare worker to an amazon S3 bucket

import aws4fetch

```
const aws4fetch = require('aws4fetch')
```

declare your access key and secret that you saved when you created in aws the iam profile with permissions at least putobject and programmatic access (secure it by passing as a resource only the arn bucket you re interested)

```
const access_key = '<access_key_id_here>';
const access_secret = '<access_secret_here>';
const region = '<region>';
const bucket = '<bucket_name>';
```

Initialize aws4fetch client

```
const aws = new aws4fetch.AwsClient({
  accessKeyId:access_key,     
  secretAccessKey:access_secret
});
const endpoint = 'https://'+bucket+'.s3.'+region+'.amazonaws.com/';



addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {
    event.respondWith(handleRequest(event.request))
});

async function handleRequest(request) {
    const filename_key = 'test.txt';

    const content = `the content of the file`;

    const res = await aws.fetch(endpoint+filename_key, 
    { body: content, method: 'PUT'})

    return new Response('ok')

}
```

Please note that you can also use aws-sdk too, which makes it more easier to interact with aws s3 but it will cost you at least 350kbytes of extra code (there is a limitation of 1mbyte worker script)

Comment: the best answer ever!

Comment: Hey i tried above it throws me below error
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error>
    <Code>AccessDenied</Code>
    <Message>Access Denied</Message>
    <RequestId>FTFJ6N9Y1NCQGDNV</RequestId>
    <HostId>JSUnHkTFSMB9srrlm7k2wzAafsbFCdfxfI2CU0J4SORiTN8ZjwwmRsWoUUc/XGWwjf+obySCSiA=</HostId>
</Error>